# Bash for loop syntax

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I'm working on getting accustomed to shell scripting and ran across a behavior I found interesting and unexplained. In the following code the first for loop will execute correctly but the second will not.

```
declare letters=(a b c d e f g)
for i in {0..7}; do
  echo ${letters[i]}
done
for i in {0..${#letters[*]}}; do
  echo ${letters[i]}
done
```

The second for loop results in the following error:

```
syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{0..7}")
```

What confuses me is that `${#letters[*]}` is clearly getting evaluated, correctly, to the number 7. But despite this the code fails even though we just saw that the same loop with `{0..7}` works perfectly fine.

What is the reason for this?

I am running OS X 10.12.2, GNU bash version 3.2.57.

Comment: Not sure about the explanation for this
But when you use {0..7} this gets expanded to
1 2 3 4 5 ... etc
But when you you {0..${#letters[*]} this expands to a string
"{0..7}" Which you can not iterate on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brace expansion occurs before parameter expansion, so you can't use a variable as part of a range.

Expand the array into a list of values:

```
for letter in "${letters[@]}"; do
    echo "$letter"
done
```

Or, expand the indices of the array into a list:

```
for i in ${!letters[@]}; do 
    echo "${letters[i]}"
done
```

As mentioned in the comments (thanks), these two approaches also accommodate sparse arrays; you can't always assume that an array defines a value for *every* index between `0` and `${#letters[@]}`.

Comment: These also accommodate sparse arrays; you can't always assume that an array defines a value for *every* index between 0 and `${#letters[@]}`.

Answer (score 5):

The bracket expansion happens before parameter expansion (see EXPANSIONS in `man bash`), therefore it works for literals only. In other words, you can't use brace expansion with variables.

You can use a C-style loop:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#letters[@]}; i++)) ; do
    echo ${letters[i]}
done
```

or an external command like `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq 1 ${#letters[@]}) ; do
    echo ${letters[i-1]}
done
```

But you usually don't need the indices, instead one loops over the elements themselves, see @TomFenech's answer below. He also shows another way of getting the list of indices.

Note that it should be `{0..6}`, not `7`.