# mutt send email to variable list from file

Tags: bash, mutt

I setup mutt and msmtp to send email via my google account. 
Another script have a variable `status.txt` output like this:

```
newyork@mydomain.com
paris@mydomain.com
berlin@mydomain.com
```

How could I send email to this list, with `status.txt` content as body ?
Something like this:

```
mutt -s 'my list' $listemail < /pathto/status.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does `$listemail` contain? and what is _not_ working here?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162615/bash-for-loop-syntax) how to write `for` loops.

Comment: listemail=my email list=status.txt contain

Comment: @Snowman: what is not working then? seems ok

Comment: doesn't work. the $listemail must be my list of emails:

newyork@mydomain.com
paris@mydomain.com
berlin@mydomain.com
...
If I define listemail="cat /pathto/status.txt" then mutt send email to : "cat@mydomain.com" and "/pathto/status.txt@mydomain.com".

Answer (score 1):

I found that this code worked for me:

```
while read line 
do mutt $line -s 'subject-mylist' < /pahthto/status.txt 
done < /pathto/listemails.txt
```

thanks for all!