# Parsing variable in loop incorrectly

Tags: zsh

No idea where I was wrong. Here's the code:

```
echo_dates() {
  local number_of_days=$1
  for i in {0..$number_of_days}; do
    echo $(date --date="$i days ago")
  done
}
echo_dates 10
```

The error:

> date: invalid date ‘{0..10} days ago’

However, this code

```
local number_of_days=10
for i in {0..$number_of_days}; do
  echo $(date --date="$i days ago")
done
```

leads to the expected result:

```
Sat 28 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
Fri 27 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
Thu 26 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
Wed 25 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
Tue 24 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
Mon 23 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
Sun 22 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
Sat 21 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
Fri 20 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
Thu 19 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
Wed 18 Dec 2019 10:51:53 PM +07
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162615/bash-for-loop-syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash for loop syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162615/bash-for-loop-syntax)

Comment: Still not fully understand yet, give at peek a my updated question. The 2 syntaxes seem to be the same to me but one works and one doesn't.

Comment: @sshashank124 : This explains, why the first code results in this error, but it does not explain, why the second code does **not** result in the same error. I would have expected an error message in both cases.

Comment: This is [BashPitfalls #33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D).

Comment: @LarryN : I don't think that you executed both of your cases under bash, or at least not under the same version of bash, because for version 4.4 (which I have) both should result in an error. If you for instance used Zsh, both cases would work without error message.

Comment: BTW, `echo $(somecommand)` is unconditionally worse than just running `somecommand` with no command substitution; it introduces inefficiency (invoking a subshell) and bugs (string-splitting and globbing output before passing it to `echo`) for no benefit. If one wants to collect all output and try to do a single write at the end, at least quote: `echo "$(somecommand)"` avoids the word-splitting and globbing steps, even though it's still adding inefficiency.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As I understand, I should end up with the C style for loop, shouldn't I?

Comment: @user1934428 I ran both under `zsh 5.5.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @user1934428 You're right, both work now when I'm attempting to reproduce the problem to take the screenshot. Have no idea why it didn't work *(I actually tested 3-4 times before posting this question because it obviously nonsense)*. But anyway, it's clear now. Thank you for being so helpful people!!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In my real problem I assigned that `command`'s result into an variable, from [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/) I have 2 options, the `$()` syntax and the backticks `` one. Was I do it correct with the `$()`?

Comment: @LarryN, `$( )` is preferable whenever you're selecting a command substitution syntax to use with any shell designed in the last 30 years. It's equally standards-compliant (being part of the POSIX sh specification from its original 1992 publication), and generally more predictable and better-behaved (doesn't require extra escaping or modify the meaning of the backslash character when nested).

Comment: @LarryN, ...ahh -- if the target is zsh rather than bash, in the future, please do tag appropriately; they're not at all mutually compatible. (Personally, I live in the bash world, considering zsh's decisions to break the POSIX standard to fix places where the folks building that standard made admittedly poor decisions one that does more harm than good by training folks to write code that misbehaves in subtle ways when run on POSIX-compliant shells; obviously, there's a differing point of view, with its own compelling arguments and adherents thereto).

Comment: ...going back to `echo`, though, when your shell is bash, always use `echo "$foo"` instead of `echo $foo` (or better, `printf '%s\n' "$foo"`; for details, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113)

Comment: Ok thank you, hadn't known that they're different. I downloaded `zsh` just to add [the theme](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#oh-my-zsh) for a more beautiful terminal, that's the only reason. Hadn't used the commands beyond the basic on terminal before.